# Converting Symphony Response to Illuminate Response(Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I'm using a third party package which returns `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` but my application must only accept `Illuminate\Http\Response`. Is there a way to convert the Symphony response to Laravel response class?

Something like `Illuminate\Http\Response::from($symphonyResponse)`

Or I will have to do something of this sort?

```
$symphonyResponse.....

$laravelResponse = new (
    $symphonyResponse->getContent(),
    $symphonyResponse->getStatusCode(),
    $symphonyResponse->headers->all()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel Doc

> A Response instance inherits from the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response class, which provides a variety of methods for building HTTP responses

Why do not return `response($symphonyResponse)`

Comment: That would take the $symphonyResponse as the first parameter for the response helper function. As the $content variable. And converting the respons class ends up in meaningless stream of characters like:
ents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 893 >> stream x��V�n1u_����t�����&Z U%B���6MK���B@Я�_� <� H

Comment: Then, probably you have to return something like response`($symphonyResponse->getContent())`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the `Request::createFromBase()` method to generate an Illuminate Request from the symphony Request:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

$illuminateRequest = Request::createFromBase($symfonyRequest);
```

From the Laravel docs for [Request->createFromBase()](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_createFromBase)